# Proving a quotient group is not Abelian without calculating actual cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Given the normal subgroup of S4: N={(1),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)}, show that S4/N is not Abelian.

What I did was to calculate two random cosets of N in S4,like in the picture I attached, and show they do not commute. This was kind of tedious, is there a more clever way to show it?

[image]

Comment: Not sure this is much simpler, but it is an alternate technique: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715857/non-commutative-quotient-group   (See the second answer)

Answer (score 5):

Here is an entirely different argument:

First observe that $|S_4/N|=6$. The only groups of order 6 are $S_3$ and $C_6$. Since $S_4$ contains no element of order 6, it follows that $S_4/N$ contains no element of order 6 and therefore $S_4/N\equiv S_3$ which is non-abelian.

Comment: Just for the OP's sake $C_6$ may be better recognized as $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Answer (score 3):

All right if G is a group and H is a normal sub group, you can easily prove that G/H is abelian iff H contains all of the commutators of G.

So let's say you pick up a=(123) b=(23)
Then the commutator is (123)(23)(321)(23)=(132) which in the given problem,N does not have. So the quotient group is not abelian

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I haven't studied commutators yet... This is a question in Normal subgroups

Comment: Don't be intimidated! The concept is Not so hard. commutator of two elements a,b in a group is a•b•a^(-1)•b^(-1). You can prove the statement i gave you easily. Nx•Ny=Ny•Nxif the quotient group is abelian so Nxy=Nyx so N=Nxyx^(-1)y^(-1) then xyx^(-1)y^(-1) belongs to N. Not so tough!